# How to add an text entry to automatically complete a form in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

In Google Chrome, when I type something to an textbox, such as my email address or an username for a website, Chrome remembers it. The next time I log in to that website, I just type some first letter and a drop-down menu appears let me choose the data i want to type. But sometimes It doesn't work. How can I add a text I want for Chrome auto complete it.
Funny, I know to remove an entry, just choose it and press "del"; but don't know how to add.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The other thing to remember is sometimes folks name their fields differently and Chrome has a hard time guessing which field is what, so you don't get a dropdown entry.

Comment: You can also utilize [AutoHotkey's](https://www.autohotkey.com/) hotscripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating address profile.

Go to google chrome **settings** ---> (scroll down) **Show Advanced Settings** ----> (scroll down) Under **Passwords And Forms** click **Manage Auto Fill Settings** ----> **Add New Street Address** ----> Enter required fields ----> Done :)

Also you can create multiple address profiles too. The profile details will fill out automatically in **almost** forms.

[ Ensure the **Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click** is **ticked** ]

Answer (score 0):

You press Enter on the keyboard when you have it entered, instead of the 'submit' button.  However, there seems to be a difference between an input wrapped in the  tag (using a 'submit' button) vs. javascript getting the .value.